# Smoke animation not showing in viewport 2.78 (iMac OS Sierra and Surface Pro3)

Tags: animation, 3d-view, smoke-simulation

I'm new to Blender and hope this is an easy fix that I missed. Running current Blender and using this on an iMac up to date as well as Surface Pro3 up to date.

I'm following a tutorial by Blender Guru on YT, it finished with adding smoke to the monkey head mesh object using quick smoke option. The smoke animated the first time in the viewport. When I try to switch to smoke+flame or just frame nothing shows other than the monkey head in the viewport. I try switching back to smoke and the smoke doesn't show anymore? This is the case for both my computers I tried this on. I closed the program and tried several times with similar results.

Is this just my computers not keeping up, or something that I should expect?

Comment: Did you press Alt+A to run the simulation?

Comment: Yes, tried alt+a as well as the physical play button. Just tried again just now and the smoke did not animate?

Comment: I also just noticed that if I switch from "Flow" to "Domain" in the physics area it will show and animate the smoke, but won't allow me to view any of the other options such as fire or smoke+fire?